# How to write a python function to return True when there's even number of 0 in a integer and return False otherwise using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

I am asked to write a function that returns True if there's even number of 0 digits in a positive integer and return False otherwise (using recursion). As an attempt, I have written a function that counts the number of 0 in an integer. May I know how can I modify the program so that it will return True and False?

```
def valid(n):
    number = str(n)
    position = number.find("0")

    if "0" not in number:
        return 0

    return 1 + valid(number[(position+1):])


print(valid(12340006))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can note that

- [recursion base] Single zero is invalid, other single digit is valid
- [recursion step] When we see non-zero digit, nothing should change (check for remaining part should give same result). When we see zero, we should invert the result (if it was odd count before, now it's even, and vice versa).

```py
def is_valid(num):
    n, r = divmod(num, 10)
    if n == 0:
        return r != 0
    return is_valid(n) ^ (r == 0)
```

Comment: Oh this is very nice. Perhaps the kind of code to make your colleagues curse your name ;) Can I ask - it looks like you have a process for designing a recursive solution. Can you say what it is / where you learned it?

Comment: @JackDeeth It's more the way how I prefer to think about recursion than a real technology. For me it's most convenient to create a recursive solution like the following: "We have some basic formats/inputs which don't require additional processing - it's the base, single digit is valid iff it's nonzero, and there can't be less than 1 digit in a number. Then if input differs - we should process it and call the function with modified argument - it's the step. Let us take least significant digit `d` and process the remaining, how should we interpret result of nested call? ...

Comment: If `d==0`, then invert it (because...), otherwise return unchanged. Will this process converge? Yes: on every step we decrease digits count by one and it will reach 1 at some point." Naming is inspired by mathematical induction scheme: base is simple case for which statement A holds and step assumes statement A holds for some point and proves that statement A also holds for next point. Recursion works in other direction, but there are most intuitive terms for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
def valid(n):
    number = str(n)
    position = number.find("0")
    if "0" not in number:
        return 0
    return 1 + valid(number[(position+1):])
print("True" if valid(12340006)%2 ==0 else "False")
```

Comment: I guess this works. However, I am asked to write a function that returns True if there's even number of 0 digits in a positive integer and return False otherwise (using recursion). So, the function cannot return an integer. The difficulty I have is to make the function return Boolean values. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: You could rename this function to `_valid`, and write a wrapper function: `def valid(n): return bool(_valid(n))`

Answer (score 0):

You have a number, don't convert to string but rather use `divmod` and division by 10:

```
def valid(num, count=0):
    num, r = divmod(num, 10) # extract the last digit (r)
    if num == 0:             # we exhausted the number
        return count%2==0    # is there an even number of zeros?
    else:
        return valid(num, count=count+int(r==0))
```

###### handling 0 -> False:

```
def valid(num, count=None):
    if count is None:
        count = int(num==0)
    num, r = divmod(num, 10)
    if num == 0:
        return count%2==0
    else:
        return valid(num, count=count+int(r==0))
```

Example:

```
>>> valid(12340006)
False

>>> valid(10203)
True

>>> valid(0)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out!! But in the question, it is stated that the function should take only one argument. May I know how can I do that?

Comment: Will fail for input `0`: it's invalid, return is True.

Comment: @SUTerliakov this is an ambiguous one (0 is the only number with a permitted leading zero), but easily fixed (see update)

Comment: Ough, @mozway, I'm sorry for quick comment. It fails for 0, but problem was stated explicitly for positive numbers, not non-negative.

Comment: @mozway But no, that's not a fix! Now zero gives `True` properly, but other single digit (e.g. `8`) produces `False` which is incorrect. Also note redundant `if num == 0 or num < 10`, first implies second and can be safely omitted.

Comment: @SUTerliakov yes, I was busy, this was silly ;) An explicit initial check is better

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `0` returned from the `if "0" not in number` condition. You can try this way:

```
def valid(n):
    
    zeros = str(n).count("0")
    
    if zeros == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return zeros % 2 == 0
```

Which should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting the number to a string using `str`, then you don't have to implement your own loop using recursion. You can count the number of `'0'` in the string using `str.count`, then test whether that number is odd or even using `%`.

```py
def is_valid(n):
    s = str(n)
    nb_of_zeroes = s.count('0')
    return (nb_of_zeroes % 2 == 0)
```

If you want to implement the logic yourself, rather than using `str` and `count`, then you can loop on the digits of `n` with `divmod(n, 10)` to extract `n%10` (the unit digit) and `n//10` (the number without its unit digit). For instance, `divmod(9836, 10)` is `(983, 6)`.

```py
def is_valid(n):
    if n == 0:
        return False  # special case for 0 which is a bit different from other numbers
    else:
        nb_of_zeroes = 0
        while n >= 10:
            n,u = divmod(n, 10)
            if u == 0:
                nb_of_zeroes += 1
        return (nb_of_zeroes % 2 == 0)
```